# Oracle JDK 11 and JDK 12 font rendering difference

Tags: java, fonts

I upgraded from Oracle JDK11 to Oracle JDK 12 and 14 and noticed that the later versions (12 and 14) seem to have a problem rendering the font "MS Reference Sans Serif".  Anyone know why and how to fix?  I suspect it could be related to the specific font.  Maybe they dropped TrueType, FreeType or whatever render they use support for it in JDK 12.  I don't see the same issue with other fonts.  I guess I could simply change the font, but I like this particular font and would like to get it working if possible.

Oracle JDK 11:

[image]

Oracle JDK 14:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaFontTest extends JPanel {
    public JavaFontTest() {
        setBackground(Color.blue);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        g.drawString("The Quick Brown Fox", 0, 30);
        g.drawString("Jumped over the Well", 0, 60);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(jf.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        jf.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jf.add(new JavaFontTest());
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the font to "Sans Serif" and it's acceptable.  It appears that Sans Serif is a "built-in" java font.  So should also be cross-platform.  Still not sure why upgrading the JDK from 11 to 12 broke the font. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html#logical-fonts

Comment: I can confirm this problem, but did not find any related bug in the OpenJDK bug tracker. I think it would make sense to file one, because on JDK 14 it is still the same problem. Listing the installed fonts and metrics did not show any differences on my machine. The way **algorithmic styling** is calculated/rendered for fonts which do not have their own bold/italic variants seems to have changed in between JDK versions.

Comment: But I also noticed that in JDK 11 italic for that font is not rendered at all, in later JDK versions an italic font is synthesised and looks okay. But the bold font really looks bad in the newer JDK versions.